# How to enforce ordering of measure group list when clients connect to SSAS via a client such as excel

Tags: excel, ssas, bids

When you connect to SSAS cubes via a client, such as Microsoft Excel, the measure groups available are displayed on the right hand side by default and they are displayed in 
alphabetical order.

Is there anyway I can enforce ordering of how these are displayed from the client, by configuring this from SSAS? Say for example, a couple of 
measure groups are used much more frequently than others - and I want these to be displayed at the top. Is enforcing this possible?

Comment: I would not think there is any way to achieve that, as I think it is Excel that applies the alphabetical ordering. The only thing you can do is of course rename he measure groups so that the alphabetical ordering is the required one, e. g. naming them "01_Orders", "02_Sales", "03_Inventory".